# pyspark cartesian join : renaming duplicate columns

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe , and i want to perform cartesian join on itself.
I used below function in pyspark

```
# Cross Join
m_f_1 =  m_f_0.withColumnRenamed('value', 'value_x').crossJoin(m_f_0.withColumnRenamed('value', 'value_y')).drop(m_f_0.area).drop(m_f_0.id)
```

The problem I am facing is there is one more column names type and I want it to renamed while performing cross join. How to do it?

m_f_0 dataframe is :

```
     id   value    area type
1: 100003 66007 Unknown  mo
2: 100011 81716 Unknown  mo
3: 100011 68028 Unknown  mo
4: 100018 48358 Unknown  mo
```

Output I expect in below format after results of crossjoin.

```
id value_x value_y type_x type_y
1: 
2:
3:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

m_f_x = m_f_0.select([F.col(c).alias('%s_x'%(c)) for c in list(m_f_0.columns)])

m_f_y = m_f_0.select([F.col(c).alias('%s_y'%(c)) for c in list(m_f_0.columns)])

m_f_1 =  (m_f_x.crossJoin(m_f_y).drop(m_f_x.area_x)
.drop(m_f_x.id_x))
```

Comment: It throws error while iterting for loop for fetctning column names
"NameError: name 'column' is not defined". I also tried changing it but no help

Comment: sorry, that's a typo of mine, in the second expression it should be `m_f_1.columns` not `m_f_0.columns`. I will edit and correct, let me know if that works

Comment: I used m_f_1.columns, still issue was there

Comment: df = m_f_0.select([F.col(c).alias('%s_x'%(c)) for c in list(m_f_0.columns)])  will solve the issue, Thanks@ags29 for help